# How to compare two Negative Binomial samples with different parameters

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

I found similar questions on CrossValidated, but none of them answer this question directly.

I have two ordered samples, from RVs: $\xi_1 \sim NB(size=r_1, prob=p_1)$ and $\xi_2 \sim NB(size=r_2, prob=p_2)$. I can estimate these parameters using `fitdist` from `MASS`. I want to compare, for example, $i$-th element of sample 1 against $i$-th element of sample 2.

**Question**: how to make my samples comparable? (I've tried different transformations, like box-cox + standartisation, but it is ridiculous). Quantile normalisation can be an option, but **are there other methods, like z-scores for normal distribution?**

Comment: Are you asking for a transformation that'd take one NB-distributed r.v. into another with a different size parameter?

Comment: @Scortchi no, I asked this before and I know how to do it. But I do not know how to do it with real dataset, i.e., toy example, I have ordered vector of $rnbinom(100, size=100, p=0.5)$ and I want to compare it with ordered vector from $rnbinom(100, size=110, p=0.5)$. I can use p-values instead of numbers, however, I would like to use numbers (they have some properties).

Comment: What, more precisely, do you mean by "comparable"?

Comment: @jbowman I mean - we have vectors of $v_i = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. I want to find such $x_j$ in $v_i$ that are higher/lower than expected. In practice - I want to find genes that are differentially expressed. Existing algorithms assume that variance across the samples is the same - they just normalise everything on $sum(x_j)$, but variance remains uneven between samples...